# How can I apply groupBy for multiple Observables what has .getId()

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Basically I've got

```
Observable<T1> obs1;
Observable<T2> obs2;
Observable<T3> obs3;
```

And both T1, T2, T3 extends T which has getId() -> I want to apply groupBy for both Observables.

I looked at zip/combineLatest but they work with the latest values (and I don't want to use toMap, either).

**UPD**: Basically you may think of obs1 as a Observable.fromIterable(map.values()), obs2 = Observable.fromIterable(map.values()), etc and what I really want is to combine the values for every key. So it may be: key#1: (null, valOfT2, null), key#2: (valOfT1, valOfT2, valOfT3), etc. I probably could use toMap and then just union the set of keys of 3 maps and then set values iteratively to get .

Comment: Maybe map them to `T` and use `merge`?

Comment: Doesn't really look that clean, imo. I'll still have to call these T1, T2 unique methods that I'll lose when map to T. Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "apply groupBy for both"?

Comment: Basically you may think of obs1 as a Observable.fromIterable(map.values()) and what I really want is to combine the values for every key. So it may be: key#1: (null, valOfT2, null), key#2: (valOfT1, valOfT2, valOfT3), etc. I probably could use toMap and then just union the set of keys of 3 maps and then set values iteratively to get <key, Entry(T1, T2, T3)>. Does it make sense?

Comment: So what is obs2 for?

Comment: @akarnokd, updated a question.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the two and use toMultimap:

```
Observable.concat(
    Observable.fromIterable(map1.values()),
    Observable.fromIterable(map2.values())
)
.toMultimap(v -> v.getId())
```

Comment: Thanks, it does looks close to what I actually want. Is there any way to avoid losing type? I still want to work with the values from map1, map2, map3 (call some methods using these objects). Ideally I'd get id -> (value from map1, value from map2, value from map3).

Comment: You could force a common supertype via `Observable.<T>concat(...)` but otherwise, it could get challenging to recover the original types via generics.